# SQL order by list

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

Here is part of code for favourited wallpapers:

```
...
    $profile = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $id"));
    }

    if ($profile['favourites'] != '') {
        $from = (($page * $template['fav_wallpaper_limit']) - $template['fav_wallpaper_limit']);

        $favourites = substr($profile['favourites'], 2);

            /// Tried to join 2 tables, but favourites still displayed by wallpaper id 
        $sql = mysql_query("
            SELECT
            * 
            FROM 
            wallpapers AS w
            JOIN favourites AS f on f.wallpaper_id = w.id
            WHERE
            w.id IN ($favourites) AND w.published = 1
            ORDER BY 
            f.wallpaper_id LIMIT $from, $template[fav_wallpaper_limit]");
            ");
```

Problem is, that it displays wallpapers by the *id* column that is stored in **wallpapers** table. While I need to display them by how they wore favourited. The data is stored in **users** table, and have column *favourites* for each user with id list of favourited wallpapers.

EXAMPLE:
, 90, 2031, 1, 34, 460, 432, ..., 2013;

Is there any way do grab this tada and order favourites from it?

Comment: Try adding an `ORDER BY` clause to your SQL statement. You don't supply sufficient information for us to re-write your query for you. If you need that, please edit your question to include the column name for the "favourite" data, and say how you would like it sorted (i.e. 1 is 1st choice, 2 is 2nd choice or 2 means like it more than something marked 1). Sorry! I misread the question - I'll go away and research an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to do this within your PHP code:

1. Read the value of the *favourites* column;
2. Explode it into an array;
3. Iterate through the array, querying the database to get the favourites in the specified order.

The usual way to do this kind of thing is to have a seperate table, say `user_favourites` with a row for each fovourite for each user that just includes the user id and the favourite id - in this case, with an order factor as well. With the database set up this way, your can execute a query on the new `user_favourites` table, where user_id is the user id, ordered by the "order factor" to get the favourites in the right order all in one go.

Which database are you using? You *might* be able to do something like

```
SELECT _whatever_
FROM favourites
WHERE favourite_id IN (SELECT favourites FROM users)
```

and it *might* return the favourites in the correct order. I think the additional table approach is superior, if you can do it that way.

Comment: I created table favourites with every favourited wallpaper id and user_id:

`$profile = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM favourites WHERE user_id = $id")`

How can I combine it with: 
`$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * from wallpapers WHERE id IN ($favourites) AND published = 1 LIMIT $from, $template[fav_wallpaper_limit]");`